# Pressing JButton with the Enter key

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, keylistener

Im doing this program and this frame signs up the new users.

What I want is to be able to fill in each text field with the information and then to press the "Cadastrar" key ("Cadastrar" = "Sign up"), not only with the mouse but also with the "Enter" key.

I tried using a keyListener but it turned out to be a little to confusing to me.
Here's the code:

```
package grafico;


public class TelaDeCadastro extends JFrame {

    private TextField campoConfirmaSenha;
    private TextField campoNome;
    private TextField campoEmail;
    private TextField campoSenha;
    private TextField dicaDeSenha;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    public TelaDeCadastro() {
        setResizable(false);
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                TelaDeCadastro.class.getResource("/Files/CashLog.png")));
        setTitle("Cadastro");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JButton botaoCadastrar = new JButton("Cadastrar");
        botaoCadastrar.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

                }
            }
        });
        botaoCadastrar.setBounds(139, 196, 115, 35);
        JButton botaoVoltar = new JButton("Voltar");
        botaoVoltar.setBounds(10, 231, 90, 30);
        JButton botaoSair = new JButton("Sair");
        botaoSair.setBounds(294, 231, 90, 30);

        ButtonGroup botoesRetorno = new ButtonGroup();
        botoesRetorno.add(botaoSair);
        botoesRetorno.add(botaoVoltar);

        // botão para submeter as informações passadas
        botaoCadastrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        });

        // botão sair fecha o programa
        botaoSair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        // botão voltar retorna para a tela de login
        botaoVoltar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(null);

        dicaDeSenha = new TextField();
        dicaDeSenha.setBounds(109, 159, 265, 22);
        container.add(dicaDeSenha);

        campoConfirmaSenha = new TextField();
        campoConfirmaSenha.setEchoChar('*');
        campoConfirmaSenha.setBounds(138, 126, 236, 23);
        container.add(campoConfirmaSenha);
        campoSenha = new TextField();
        campoSenha.setEchoChar('*');
        campoSenha.setBounds(109, 93, 265, 23);
        container.add(campoSenha);
        campoEmail = new TextField();
        campoEmail.setBounds(109, 62, 265, 23);
        container.add(campoEmail);
        campoNome = new TextField();
        campoNome.setBounds(109, 31, 265, 23);
        container.add(campoNome);

        JLabel labelNome = new javax.swing.JLabel("Seu nome:");
        labelNome.setBounds(10, 35, 364, 14);
        container.add(labelNome);
        JLabel labelEmail = new javax.swing.JLabel("Seu Email:");
        labelEmail.setBounds(10, 66, 364, 14);
        container.add(labelEmail);
        JLabel labelSenha = new javax.swing.JLabel("Sua senha:");
        labelSenha.setBounds(10, 95, 364, 14);
        container.add(labelSenha);

        JLabel lblConfirmarSenha = new JLabel("Confirmar senha:");
        lblConfirmarSenha.setBounds(10, 126, 122, 15);
        container.add(lblConfirmarSenha);

        JLabel lblDicaDaSenha = new JLabel("Dica da senha:");
        lblDicaDaSenha.setBounds(10, 162, 90, 14);
        container.add(lblDicaDaSenha);
        container.add(botaoCadastrar);
        container.add(botaoVoltar);
        container.add(botaoSair);
        getContentPane().add(container);

        JLabel lblCadastrese = new JLabel("Cadastre-se:");
        lblCadastrese.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblCadastrese.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblCadastrese.setBounds(10, 9, 364, 14);
        container.add(lblCadastrese);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(TelaDeCadastro.class
                .getResource("/Files/conta-sem-tarifa.jpg")));
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 300);
        container.add(label);
        pack();
    }

    public TextField getCampoConfirmaSenha() {

    public TextField getCampoNome() {

    public TextField getCampoEmail() {

    public TextField getCampoSenha() {

    public TextField getDicaDeSenha() {
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Also, beware of mixing AWT (heavy weight) and Swing (light weight) components, this may not end nicely...

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `KeyListener` (or for that matter `MouseListener`) with buttons.

Buttons are backed by the `ActionListener` API which deals with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, other platform specific activation key strokes, left mouse clicks and mnemonics automatically...

Take a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details.

You should also have a look at [How to Use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html), as `JRootPane` allows you to define a "default" button which will be actived when the user presses the "activation" key stroke.  Just beware, that if the component with focus consumes that event, it won't active the button though

Generally speaking, you should avoid `KeyListener` where ever possible and favor the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead anyway

Comment: *"yes you are right"* - Not always, but this is one of those times where it just irritates me ;)

Comment: why it irritates you? :)

Comment: Because there's a well document and demonstrated way to use the API which provides for consistent usage across multiple platforms. Trying to do anything else breaks that and it just irritates me :P - I work across multiple platforms and it irritates me when a program doesn't conform to known conventions without a damn good reason :P

Comment: Some programmer never wants to read the documentation, they just keep it aside and start coding as me :)

Comment: That will come back to bite you, especially when you run into a Linux or Mac user, they won't love you for it ;)